# Is it possible with php to display all the tags used in a html document?

Tags: php

Pardon me if this has already been asked, but i couldn't find it.

I need a php script that displays all the tags that are in use in the website page that it just loaded.

Am working on a php project, by using php in style sheets.

Example:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/css; charset:UTF-8');
    $url_color = "#3465A4";
?>

a {
    color: <?php echo "$url_color"; ?>;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

The desired end result: When loaded a page with the script, it only loads the aforementioned tags css's!

Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you try sass or less?

Answer (score 0):

Basically to do what you are looking for might be an over burden of work. Basically you will need the following

- Database/file to store the classes that can be updated
- HTML DOM parser *ex: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/*

  - This causes a page to be loaded twice in order to get the tags and classes
- Ability to match tags and classes

You may want to look into CSS alternatives, like SASS or Less